# Python Postgres: WHERE on a date-Field

Tags: python, postgresql, date, filter, sqlalchemy

I defined a table ABC with the field "date".
Setting the date-filter has no effect. I get all entries. If I combine the filter (id='...' and date='...') only the id filter has an effect...

Has anybody an idea how I can filter?

```py
ABC= Table("abc", METADATA,
    Column("id", UUID, primary_key=True),
    Column("zzz_id", UUID, ForeignKey("zzz.id"), nullable=False),
    ...
    Column("date", Date, nullable=False)
)

session.select(
        ABC,
        # where= ABC.c.date == '2019-06-26'
        # where= ABC.c.date == datetime.date(2019, 6, 26)
        # where= ABC.c.date == datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26)
    )
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That should include a small sample of your data, and expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.select([ABC]).where(ABC.date == '2019-06-26')
```